# No root directory found error during installation?

Tags: system-installation

I get this error and it says to correct using the partitioner.  Any attempt to do so crashes the intaller.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you are doing I recommend to use different distribution, like **gParted**. You didn't specified version, do you use latest Elementary version?